# compare values of two arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

First one:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => string '7' (length=1)
  4 => string '8' (length=1)
  5 => string '9' (length=1)
```

Second one:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '9' (length=1)
```

I need to compare these two arrays, and store the matching values in another array `matching`. Those who don't match should be stored in `not_matching`.

How should I get this done? Are there functions available for this purpose?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may search **before** ask. There are tons of answers to this same question

Comment: I did search for it, but with the wrong keywords. I ended up with `in_array`...

Comment: Ok, no problem, but in stackoverflow is easy to find something, and in Google is easiest!!

Comment: It also works with `in_array`. So I was in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

For matching
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_intersect

```
$result=array_intersect($array1,$array2);
print_r($result,1);
```

For not matching 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_diff

```
$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

For custom code

```
$match_array = array();
$un_match_array = array();
foreach( $array1 as $arr )
{
  if( in_array($arr, $array2) )
  {
      $match_array[] = $arr;
  }
  else
  {
     $un_match_array[] = $arr;
  }
}
print_r($match_array,1);
print_r($un_match_array,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the matching results : `array_intersect()`

https://php.net/array_intersect

To get the not matching results : `array_diff()`

https://php.net/array_diff